# MySQL Join 3 Tables with Count, Group & Where/Having Clause

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I have 3 tables

```
TABLE ii_ProductCategory
-------------------
id    title  

TABLE ii_Product2Category
-------------------
categoryId    productId

TABLE ii_Product
----------------
id    minPrice
```

I want to find all Categories are either not contained in  ii_Product2Category at all or are only linked to products that have minPrice IS NULL.

Here is my attempt. I am getting a GROUP BY ERROR.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p2c.`categoryId`) as "ProdCount",  
    cat.`id`,
    cat.`title`,
    prod.`minPrice`
FROM `ii_ProductCategory` cat  
LEFT JOIN `ii_Product2Category` p2c 
    ON p2c.`categoryId` = cat.`id`
LEFT JOIN `ii_Product` prod
    ON p2c.`productId` = prod.`id`
WHERE prod.`minPrice` IS NULL
    AND COUNT(DISTINCT p2c.`categoryId`) = 0
GROUP BY cat.`id`
```

I tried moving the `prod.minPrice IS NULL` to a HAVING on the join but that didn't work either. I also want to be able to drop the `AND COUNT(DISTINCT p2c.categoryId) = 0` and sort by ProdCount so I can see total numbers of products in each whether they are null or not.

Comment: Change "AND" to "HAVING" and move that line to the very bottom

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to not grouping the non-aggregated columns.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p2c.`categoryId`) as "ProdCount",  
    cat.`id`,
    cat.`title`,
    prod.`minPrice`
FROM `ii_ProductCategory` cat  
LEFT JOIN `ii_Product2Category` p2c 
    ON p2c.`categoryId` = cat.`id`
LEFT JOIN `ii_Product` prod
    ON p2c.`productId` = prod.`id`
WHERE prod.`minPrice` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cat.`id`, cat.`title`, prod.`minPrice`
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p2c.`categoryId`) = 0
```

Comment: I just want to see a list of my catagories.
`GROUP BY cat.id, cat.title, prod.minPrice`
Returns duplicates of each category title. 
`GROUP BY cat.id` is what I need.

Comment: See my updates. I need to know which categories only have products with minPrice IS NULL or have no products at all.